# Unexpected behavior of matplotlib.patches upon window resizing

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, resize

I am working on a Python 3.4 application for displaying power spectral density graphs for EEG signals. I want to superimpose color patches on the graphs to indicate standard frequency bands for delta, theta, alpha, beta and gamma.

The skeleton program below shows how a graph appears in a popup window when the Display button is pressed. Everything is fine when resizing the first popup. The problem occurs when resizing a second popup window (by clicking on the Display button a second time). Then, color patches appear at incorrect locations and do not correspond to the indicated frequency bands.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import BOTH, TOP, Y
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Frame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg

# The following is used for psd semi-log graphs only
XMIN = 0 # minimum frequency
XMAX = 55 # maximum frequency
YMIN = 0.1 # minimum PSD value
YMAX = 100 # maximum PSD value
lblY = YMAX - 30

band_patches = [
    patches.Rectangle((XMIN, YMIN), 4, YMAX, facecolor="blue", alpha=0.2),
    patches.Rectangle((4, YMIN), 4, YMAX, facecolor="cyan", alpha=0.2),
    patches.Rectangle((8, YMIN), 4, YMAX, facecolor="green", alpha=0.2),
    patches.Rectangle((12, YMIN), 18, YMAX, facecolor="orange", alpha=0.2),
    patches.Rectangle((30, YMIN), XMAX-30, YMAX, facecolor="magenta", alpha=0.2),
]


class PV(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, name='demo'):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, name=name)
        self.pack(expand=Y, fill=BOTH)
        self.master.title('Demo')
        self._create_viewer_panel()

    def _create_viewer_panel(self):
        viewerPanel = Frame(self, name='pv')
        viewerPanel.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=Y)
        # create the notebook
        nb = ttk.Notebook(viewerPanel, name='notebook')
        nb.enable_traversal()
        nb.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=Y, padx=2, pady=3)
        self._create_UI_tab(nb)  #NEW

    def _create_UI_tab(self, nb):
        # frame to hold contentx
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(nb, height='10i', width='8i', name='main')
        btn0 = ttk.Button(self.frame, text='Display', width='25', command=self.draw_psd)
        btn0.grid(row=0, column=1)
        # add to notebook (underline = index for short-cut character)
        nb.add(self.frame, text='Main', underline=0, padding=2)

    def draw_psd(self):
        popup = tk.Tk()
        popup.geometry('720x480') # Set dimensions of popup window to 800x500 pixels
        popup.wm_title("Power Spectral Density")
        p = plt.figure()
        self.ax = plt.subplot(111)

        box = self.ax.get_position()
        self.ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width, box.height*0.95])

        self.ax.set_yscale('log')
        self.ax.set_xscale('linear')
        plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
        plt.xlim(XMIN, XMAX)
        plt.ylim(YMIN, YMAX)
        for ptch in band_patches:
            self.ax.add_patch(ptch)
        self.ax.annotate('delta', xy=(2,lblY), fontsize=10, color=None, horizontalalignment='center')
        self.ax.annotate('theta', xy=(6,lblY), fontsize=10, color=None, horizontalalignment='center')
        self.ax.annotate('alpha', xy=(10,lblY), fontsize=10, color=None, horizontalalignment='center')
        self.ax.annotate('beta', xy=(21,lblY), fontsize=10, color=None, horizontalalignment='center')
        self.ax.annotate('gamma', xy=(42,lblY), fontsize=10, color=None, horizontalalignment='center')

        plt.show()

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(p, master=popup)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, popup)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=1)

        popup.mainloop()
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PV().mainloop()
```

I suspect that it's a problem with initializing coordinates but I'm at a loss as to how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to redefine the patches for each new plot - in order
for their "transforms" to work properly.

You should only have one Tk instance per application. For secondary windows
use Toplevel.

Also, when you're embedding matplotlib into a tkinter application, it's
best to avoid the so-called "pyplot interface" - plt.show() etc. Instead,
use the matplotlib API explicitly: plt.xlabel(...) -> ax.set_xlabel(...)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import BOTH, TOP, Y
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Frame, Toplevel
##import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg


XMIN = 0 # minimum frequency
XMAX = 55 # maximum frequency
YMIN = 0.1 # minimum PSD value
YMAX = 100 # maximum PSD value
lblY = YMAX - 30

##band_patches = [
##    patches.Rectangle((XMIN, YMIN), 4, YMAX, facecolor="blue", alpha=0.2),
##    patches.Rectangle((4, YMIN), 4, YMAX, facecolor="cyan", alpha=0.2),
##    patches.Rectangle((8, YMIN), 4, YMAX, facecolor="green", alpha=0.2),
##    patches.Rectangle((12, YMIN), 18, YMAX, facecolor="orange", alpha=0.2),
##    patches.Rectangle((30, YMIN), XMAX-30, YMAX, facecolor="magenta", alpha=0.2),
##]

class WinPsd(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, cnf={}, **kw):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master, **kw)
        self._create_plot()

    def _create_plot(self):
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        ax = self.ax
        box = ax.get_position()
        ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width, box.height*0.95])

        ax.set_yscale('log')
        ax.set_xscale('linear')

        ax.set_xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
        ax.set_xlim(XMIN, XMAX)
        ax.set_ylim(YMIN, YMAX)

        band_patches = [
                        patches.Rectangle((XMIN, YMIN), 4, YMAX,
                                          facecolor="blue", alpha=0.2
                                          ),
                        patches.Rectangle((4, YMIN), 4, YMAX,
                                          facecolor="cyan", alpha=0.2
                                          ),
                        patches.Rectangle((8, YMIN), 4, YMAX,
                                          facecolor="green", alpha=0.2
                                          ),
                        patches.Rectangle((12, YMIN), 18, YMAX,
                                          facecolor="orange", alpha=0.2
                                          ),
                        patches.Rectangle((30, YMIN), XMAX-30, YMAX,
                                          facecolor="magenta", alpha=0.2
                                          ),
                       ]

        for ptch in band_patches:
            ax.add_patch(ptch)
        ax.annotate('delta', xy=(2,lblY), fontsize=10, color=None, horizontalalignment='center')
        ax.annotate('theta', xy=(6,lblY), fontsize=10, color=None, horizontalalignment='center')
        ax.annotate('alpha', xy=(10,lblY), fontsize=10, color=None, horizontalalignment='center')
        ax.annotate('beta', xy=(21,lblY), fontsize=10, color=None, horizontalalignment='center')
        ax.annotate('gamma', xy=(42,lblY), fontsize=10, color=None, horizontalalignment='center')

        xdata,ydata = [],[]
        self.line, = ax.plot(xdata, ydata)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        canvas.show()

    def draw(self, xdata, ydata):
        self.line.set_xdata(xdata)
        self.line.set_ydata(ydata)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()


class WinMain(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, name='demo', **kw):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, **kw)
        self.title(name)
        self._create_viewer_panel()

    def _create_viewer_panel(self):
        viewerPanel = ttk.Frame(self, name='pv')
        viewerPanel.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=Y)
        nb = ttk.Notebook(viewerPanel, name='notebook')
        nb.enable_traversal()
        nb.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=Y, padx=2, pady=3)
        self._create_UI_tab(nb) 

    def _create_UI_tab(self, nb):
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(nb, height='10i', width='8i', name='main')
        btn0 = ttk.Button(self.frame, text='Display', width='25', command=self.show_psd)
        btn0.grid(row=0, column=1)
        nb.add(self.frame, text='Main', underline=0, padding=2)

    def show_psd(self):
        xdata,ydata = [range(50)],[range(50)] #get some data from somewhere
        popup = WinPsd(self)
        popup.wm_title("Power Spectral Density")
        popup.draw(xdata, ydata)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    WinMain().mainloop()
```

Comment: Oblivion, thank you for the insightful and remarkably helpful answer. I've implemented your suggestion to use Toplevel for secondary windows and it solves the problem of resizing these windows. Getting rid of the "pyplot interface" will be considerably harder to do-- there are dozens of occurrences of plt in my code and replacing them is not a simple matter. At the moment, popup windows for time series-graphs, spectrograms, radar charts seem to work okay. I suppose there may be hidden issues, but I don't really understand why this is a problem.